# Remove duplicate url's python beautifulsoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I want to remove the duplicate url's from the file having list of url's. it has "[http://www.naver.com/나눔글꼴.jpg](http://www.naver.com/%EB%82%98%EB%88%94%EA%B8%80%EA%BC%B4.jpg)" and  they are repeating..  here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import re
import urllib.request

p = re.compile('나눔글꼴')
html = 'http://www.naver.com'
data = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.naver.com").read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
links = p.findall(str(soup))

i = set() 
for i in links:
    link = 'http://www.naver.com/' + str(i) + '.jpg'         
    print(link)
```

Comment: You forgot to include your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to give input to the `set()` method:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
links = p.findall(str(soup))

i = set(links) 
for x in i:
    link = 'http://www.naver.com/' + str(x) + '.jpg'         
    print(link)
```